# Android touch gets unresponsive after screen on

Tags: android, touch, screen

When I press power button to get screen on, device doesn't response to any touch and it only starts working after leaving the phone in on-screen state for several minutes and this duration is totally random.

Is there any way I can obtain information whether touch is acknowledging back to system in response to the screen on event or not ?

I tried looking in logcat entries before and after pressing power key but couldn't find anything.

edit:

I just wanted to find out where the problem lies, if I pull out the battery and restarts the phone, again it responses to touch all the way good until screen gets turned off.

Comment: May be a heavy operation is making the screen un responsive. I did faced same problem but before the screen resume the touch interaction it will not show any of the log cat events.

Comment: You have to mention what you are doing ?